# How to use UIPopoverBackgroundView to present a transparent popover in iOS 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, ios6, uipopovercontroller

I am using a `UIPopoverController` to present a `UITableViewController` in iOS 6.

I am trying to make this popover semi-transparent in order to be able to show the covered views. Other than that, I would like to have a standard popover controller with default arrows etc.

Since iOS 5 it is possible to define a custom popover background view using [UIPopoverBackgroundView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverBackgroundView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIPopoverBackgroundView).
However, I am struggling to set up the background correctly. The code I am using to set up the background view is shown below. I would like to set **only the alpha value** and keep other properties set to their default values.

In addition, how would I need to **configure the table view controller presented inside the popover** to give its view (and all its subviews, except the text) transparency too.

Thank you!

```
configPopover.popoverBackgroundViewClass = [TransparentPopoverBackGroundView class];
```

**TransparentPopoverBackGroundView.m:**

```
#import "TransparentPopoverBackGroundView.h"

@implementation TransparentPopoverBackGroundView

@synthesize arrowOffset;
@synthesize arrowDirection;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.alpha = 0.4;
    }
    return self;
}

+ (UIEdgeInsets)contentViewInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5);
}

+ (CGFloat)arrowHeight{
    return 10.0;
}

+ (CGFloat)arrowBase{
    return 10.0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this [link](https://github.com/ddebin/DDPopoverBackgroundView)

Set

`#define DEFAULT_TINT_COLOR [UIColor blackColor];`

To

```
#define DEFAULT_TINT_COLOR [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: do you want to hide you tableview or set background color to transparent.

Comment: For hiding: yourpopovercontroller.tableview.alpha=0; For setting background: yourpopovercontroller.tableview.backgroundcolor=[UIColor clearcolor];

Comment: Sorry for being to vague, I would like the background of the table view presented in the popover to semi-transparent (alpha = 0.5).

Comment: Unfortunately the source code for `DDPoverBackgroundView` does not support ARC. I cannot access my tableView directly by using `[UIColor clearColor]`. Any other ideas? :-)